# Iphone:Installing CSRs on other account

Tags: iphone

I have two developer's account, one for myself and other for my partner. Initially when I got MAc I installed CSRs of both Apple account on single User of MAC. Now I heard that it could create issues while deploying so I want to remove my CSRs from main Mac User account and want to install on my own. What are the implications? Do I need to revoke/delete uploaded CSRs/other things from my Apple Developer account or use same one? The reason I asked because I heard that it generates Private Key once and can't be generated again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always export the local key store from one mac machine to the other mac. you can check the apple documentation on how to import/export local key.

If you have downloaded "iPhone Developer Program User Guide" file, check the chapter "Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems"

Thanks
Ravi